# Angular 4 Loop service function and wait for response on each call

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need to call a service function for x amount of times.
I need to wait for the response on each call and do some validation on the returned data.
I have used switchmap before but that is when I know how many calls I need to make, For example 1:Get user, 2: Get userdetails.

But now I dont know how many calls I need to make, its dynamic, it can be 1 time, it call be 10 times.
Any ides on how to do this?

Hi, thanks for the example. But if I need to loop the service call, I do this from the subscription?
And do I need to use the observer.next in the service function?

My service function looks like this:

```
getNavigation(tree: Navigation): Observable<Navigation[]> {

    return this.partfinderService.getNavigation(tree.id);

  }
```

Calling it like this :

```
this.getNavigation(this.master)
          .expand((data: Navigation[]) => {
            return this.getNavigation(data[0]);
          }).subscribe(context => contextData = context);
```

Comment: I don't have time to write a proper answer for now, but take a look at this: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/expand.html might be the solution you're looking for.

Comment: switchMap change a call by other (based in the first) forkJoin make the calls in parallel. I supouse you want to make a forkJoin and then a switchMap over a forkJoin

Comment: Maybe `takeWhile`?

Comment: @Supamiu expand looks promesing, but I cant find any exanple on how to use it with a service call.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? You need to make a service repeatedly until some validation passes? But you don't want pauses between the requests, but just send the next one the very moment you determined that the previous one didn't pass the validation?

Comment: @IngoBürk Lets say I have an array with 3 ids, 1,2.3.
I need to call a function that returns some data based on the first item in the array, add the returned data to an object, then i need to call the function again with the second item in the array, use that returned data and add to the first returned data object, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It feels like what you really need is adding ngrx store support to your angular application. [Here is where you can start](https://blog.nrwl.io/using-ngrx-4-to-manage-state-in-angular-applications-64e7a1f84b7b) if you have time to improve and refactor.

As suggested by Supamiu, the expand would do it, I made a simple stackblitz example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-48863467).

A service function :

```
      doSomething(context: any) {
      return Observable.create(function (observer) {
         setTimeout(() => {
          observer.next(
          { 
              run: context.run + 1,
              value : context.value + '- Run ' + context.run 
          });
          }, 1000);});
     }
```

A subscription :

```
    this._testService.doSomething(this.context)
    .pipe(
      expand(context => {
      return this._testService.doSomething(context)
              // Condition of the last run
             .pipe(filter(c => c.run <= 5));
      })
    ).subscribe(context => this.context = context);
```

Comment: I updated my question, can I use my service function like that?
And If I need to loop this call I do it from the component side(subscriber)?

Can I use a regular "for" loop for this?

Comment: The service was not the main purpose of the example. You can't use a for loop if your service is async.
What is the return type of the `partfinderService.getNavigation` function ?

Comment: The function returns a "Navigation" object, it just contains some values like name,id, and a property called subNavigaion, where i should put the next calls data into.

Comment: You mean `Observable<Navigation>` ? Why are you using `Observable.create` ? Can you make a stackblitz to expose your problem ?

Comment: I changed the question, added how I call it.
I think it works, but not sure if its correct.

I still need to lopp it

Comment: I think your call is actually doing an infinite loop : the expand makes a call using the previous call result. You just need to add a condition to make it do what you want.
You should debug your code, make sure that your service is working for a unique call at first.

Comment: Hm well it looks like its working, but for now the subscribe even overrides the "contextData" so I dont put the result into the previous returned data, do I handle this in the subscribtion or in the expand?